# continuous map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$ that send any convex on a convex

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, convexity

Let $f$ be a continuous fonction from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$, such that for any $a<b\in \mathbb R,\,\, f([a,b])$ is convex.

Is there a line $D\subset \mathbb R^2$ such that $f(\mathbb R)\subset D$ ?

Comment: The linked "duplicate" does, indeed, have two answers.  However, neither of them answers the question.  But perhaps one of the comments does provide a reference for an answer?

Comment: I didn't read the related articles yet, but I'm quite happy with the result announced in the comment of Jairo Bochi. If you ask only  $f([0,t])$ to be convex for all $t\in \mathbb R_+$, then there is a counterexample! I also like answers but I have to read the related articles before saying something about the fuzzy direction and ideas that are coming to me right now...  I will complete this comment If I find   relevant observations from this reading.